# upload video to vimeo with url

Tags: javascript, php, vimeo-api

I am new in vimeo. I am just uploading the video to vimeo using link. The API gives me success and video is also uploaded to vimeo, but the video is not playing and says it is corrupted. Here is reference url:
https://github.com/websemantics/vimeo-upload

This is the code:

```
me.prototype.upload = function() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.open(this.httpMethod, this.url, true)
         xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4')
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')

        xhr.onload = function(e) {
            // get vimeo upload  url, user (for available quote), ticket id and complete url
            if (e.target.status < 400) {
                var response = JSON.parse(e.target.responseText)
                this.url = response.upload_link_secure
                this.user = response.user
                this.ticket_id = response.ticket_id
                this.complete_url = defaults.api_url + response.complete_uri
              //  this.sendFile_()
            } else {
                this.onUploadError_(e)
            }
        }.bind(this)

        xhr.onerror = this.onUploadError_.bind(this)
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({

        "upload.approach" : "pull",
         "upload.link" : "https://vimeo.com/6370469"
        }))
    }
```

The Response:

```
{
    "uri": "/videos/267944773",
    "name": "Untitled",
    "description": null,
    "link": "https://vimeo.com/267944773",
    "duration": 0,
    "width": 400,
    "language": null,
    "height": 300,
    "embed": {
        "uri": null,
        "html": "<iframe src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/267944773?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&badge=0&autopause=0&player_id=0&app_id=125909\" width=\"400\" height=\"300\" frameborder=\"0\" title=\"Untitled\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>",
        "buttons": {
            "like": true,
            "watchlater": true,
            "share": true,
            "embed": true,
            "hd": false,
            "fullscreen": true,
            "scaling": true
        },
        "logos": {
            "vimeo": true,
            "custom": {
                "active": false,
                "link": null,
                "sticky": false
            }
        },
        "title": {
            "name": "user",
            "owner": "user",
            "portrait": "user"
        },
        "playbar": true,
        "volume": true,
        "speed": false,
        "color": "00adef"
    },
    "created_time": "2018-05-04T05:15:07+00:00",
    "modified_time": "2018-05-04T05:15:07+00:00",
    "release_time": "2018-05-04T05:15:07+00:00",
    "content_rating": [
        "unrated"
    ],
    "license": null,
    "privacy": {
        "view": "anybody",
        "embed": "public",
        "download": true,
        "add": true,
        "comments": "anybody"
    },
    "pictures": {
        "uri": null,
        "active": false,
        "type": "default",
        "sizes": [
            {
                "width": 100,
                "height": 75,
                "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/default_100x75?r=pad",
                "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2Fdefault_100x75&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
            },
            {
                "width": 200,
                "height": 150,
                "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/default_200x150?r=pad",
                "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2Fdefault_200x150&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
            },
            {
                "width": 295,
                "height": 166,
                "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/default_295x166?r=pad",
                "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2Fdefault_295x166&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
            },
            {
                "width": 640,
                "height": 480,
                "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/default_640x480?r=pad",
                "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2Fdefault_640x480&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
            },
            {
                "width": 960,
                "height": 720,
                "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/default_960x720?r=pad",
                "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2Fdefault_960x720&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
            },
            {
                "width": 1280,
                "height": 960,
                "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/default_1280x960?r=pad",
                "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2Fdefault_1280x960&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
            },
            {
                "width": 1920,
                "height": 1440,
                "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/default_1920x1440?r=pad",
                "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2Fdefault_1920x1440&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
            }
        ],
        "resource_key": "7a491d0e8cad256a8ac2fd6d207e647c1b034bad"
    },
    "tags": [],
    "stats": {
        "plays": 0
    },
    "categories": [],
    "metadata": {
        "connections": {
            "comments": {
                "uri": "/videos/267944773/comments",
                "options": [
                    "GET",
                    "POST"
                ],
                "total": 0
            },
            "credits": {
                "uri": "/videos/267944773/credits",
                "options": [
                    "GET",
                    "POST"
                ],
                "total": 1
            },
            "likes": {
                "uri": "/videos/267944773/likes",
                "options": [
                    "GET"
                ],
                "total": 0
            },
            "pictures": {
                "uri": "/videos/267944773/pictures",
                "options": [
                    "GET",
                    "POST"
                ],
                "total": 0
            },
            "texttracks": {
                "uri": "/videos/267944773/texttracks",
                "options": [
                    "GET",
                    "POST"
                ],
                "total": 0
            },
            "related": null,
            "recommendations": {
                "uri": "/videos/267944773/recommendations",
                "options": [
                    "GET"
                ]
            }
        },
        "interactions": {
            "watchlater": {
                "uri": "/users/84634686/watchlater/267944773",
                "options": [
                    "GET",
                    "PUT",
                    "DELETE"
                ],
                "added": false,
                "added_time": null
            },
            "report": {
                "uri": "/videos/267944773/report",
                "options": [
                    "POST"
                ],
                "reason": [
                    "pornographic",
                    "harassment",
                    "advertisement",
                    "ripoff",
                    "incorrect rating",
                    "spam"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "user": {
        "uri": "/users/84634686",
        "name": "Lovey Singh",
        "link": "https://vimeo.com/user84634686",
        "location": null,
        "bio": null,
        "created_time": "2018-05-02T16:27:31+00:00",
        "account": "basic",
        "pictures": {
            "uri": "/users/84634686/pictures/25155707",
            "active": true,
            "type": "custom",
            "sizes": [
                {
                    "width": 30,
                    "height": 30,
                    "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/25155707_30x30"
                },
                {
                    "width": 75,
                    "height": 75,
                    "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/25155707_75x75"
                },
                {
                    "width": 100,
                    "height": 100,
                    "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/25155707_100x100"
                },
                {
                    "width": 300,
                    "height": 300,
                    "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/25155707_300x300"
                },
                {
                    "width": 72,
                    "height": 72,
                    "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/25155707_72x72"
                },
                {
                    "width": 144,
                    "height": 144,
                    "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/25155707_144x144"
                },
                {
                    "width": 216,
                    "height": 216,
                    "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/25155707_216x216"
                },
                {
                    "width": 288,
                    "height": 288,
                    "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/25155707_288x288"
                },
                {
                    "width": 360,
                    "height": 360,
                    "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/25155707_360x360"
                }
            ],
            "resource_key": "7268675b46b5f07155d35ffaf0cfc98ae4d3a38b"
        },
        "websites": [],
        "metadata": {
            "connections": {
                "albums": {
                    "uri": "/users/84634686/albums",
                    "options": [
                        "GET"
                    ],
                    "total": 0
                },
                "appearances": {
                    "uri": "/users/84634686/appearances",
                    "options": [
                        "GET"
                    ],
                    "total": 0
                },
                "categories": {
                    "uri": "/users/84634686/categories",
                    "options": [
                        "GET"
                    ],
                    "total": 0
                },
                "channels": {
                    "uri": "/users/84634686/channels",
                    "options": [
                        "GET"
                    ],
                    "total": 0
                },
                "feed": {
                    "uri": "/users/84634686/feed",
                    "options": [
                        "GET"
                    ]
                },
                "followers": {
                    "uri": "/users/84634686/followers",
                    "options": [
                        "GET"
                    ],
                    "total": 0
                },
                "following": {
                    "uri": "/users/84634686/following",
                    "options": [
                        "GET"
                    ],
                    "total": 0
                },
                "groups": {
                    "uri": "/users/84634686/groups",
                    "options": [
                        "GET"
                    ],
                    "total": 0
                },
                "likes": {
                    "uri": "/users/84634686/likes",
                    "options": [
                        "GET"
                    ],
                    "total": 0
                },
                "moderated_channels": {
                    "uri": "/users/84634686/channels?filter=moderated",
                    "options": [
                        "GET"
                    ],
                    "total": 0
                },
                "portfolios": {
                    "uri": "/users/84634686/portfolios",
                    "options": [
                        "GET"
                    ],
                    "total": 0
                },
                "videos": {
                    "uri": "/users/84634686/videos",
                    "options": [
                        "GET"
                    ],
                    "total": 1
                },
                "watchlater": {
                    "uri": "/users/84634686/watchlater",
                    "options": [
                        "GET"
                    ],
                    "total": 0
                },
                "shared": {
                    "uri": "/users/84634686/shared/videos",
                    "options": [
                        "GET"
                    ],
                    "total": 0
                },
                "pictures": {
                    "uri": "/users/84634686/pictures",
                    "options": [
                        "GET",
                        "POST"
                    ],
                    "total": 1
                },
                "watched_videos": {
                    "uri": "/me/watched/videos",
                    "options": [
                        "GET"
                    ],
                    "total": 0
                },
                "block": {
                    "uri": "/me/block",
                    "options": [
                        "GET"
                    ],
                    "total": 0
                }
            }
        },
        "preferences": {
            "videos": {
                "privacy": {
                    "view": "anybody",
                    "comments": "anybody",
                    "embed": "public",
                    "download": true,
                    "add": true
                }
            }
        },
        "content_filter": [
            "language",
            "drugs",
            "violence",
            "nudity",
            "safe",
            "unrated"
        ],
        "upload_quota": {
            "space": {
                "free": 524288000,
                "max": 524288000,
                "used": 0,
                "showing": "periodic"
            },
            "periodic": {
                "free": 524288000,
                "max": 524288000,
                "used": 0,
                "reset_date": "2018-05-06T01:15:08-04:00"
            },
            "lifetime": {
                "free": 5368709120,
                "max": 5368709120,
                "used": 0
            }
        },
        "resource_key": "b03345ba2b5759492fad56d5a297636905a40336"
    },
    "review_page": null,
    "last_user_action_event_date": null,
    "app": {
        "name": "golfApi",
        "uri": "/apps/125909"
    },
    "status": "uploading",
    "resource_key": "c521dbdfa3c0ffa20a963a760a4895bd4f174e48",
    "upload": {
        "status": "in_progress",
        "upload_link": "https://1512435765.cloud.vimeo.com/upload?ticket_id=147907192&video_file_id=993214879&signature=9078eeb13ddbce78ea210f50f8a58237&v6=1&redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Fvimeo.com%2Fupload%2Fapi%3Fvideo_file_id%3D993214879%26app_id%3D125909%26ticket_id%3D147907192%26signature%3D2f9faa44050984f217c818e80ccbcb66619fd917",
        "form": "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"https://1512435765.cloud.vimeo.com/upload?ticket_id=147907192&video_file_id=993214879&signature=9078eeb13ddbce78ea210f50f8a58237&v6=1&redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Fvimeo.com%2Fupload%2Fapi%3Fvideo_file_id%3D993214879%26app_id%3D125909%26ticket_id%3D147907192%26signature%3D2f9faa44050984f217c818e80ccbcb66619fd917\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">\n<label for=\"file\">File:</label>\n<input type=\"file\" name=\"file_data\" id=\"file\"><br>\n<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">\n</form>",
        "complete_uri": null,
        "approach": "post",
        "size": null,
        "redirect_url": null,
        "link": null
    },
    "transcode": {
        "status": "in_progress"
    }
}
```

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: Please check out here already answer given https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640395/how-to-upload-video-to-vimeo-through-their-api

Answer (score 0):

The upload.link value you provide must be a direct link to a video file resource, not a web page.

For example, you provided:

`"upload.link":"https://vimeo.com/6370469"`

You'll want to use a direct link to a video file like this:

`"upload.link":"http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_480p_surround-fix.avi"`

(this is a link to an SD version of the open source film [Big Buck Bunny](http://bbb3d.renderfarming.net/download.html), commonly used for testing)

Vimeo API pull upload documentation is found here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#using-the-pull-approach